# How to mock protected virtual members in FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

Moq allows mocking protected virtual members ([see here](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/mocking-protected-members-with-moq/)). Is it possible to do the same in FakeItEasy?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It can be done, however it can not be done out of the box. The trick is to implement IFakeObjectCallRule and add it to your fake through Fake.GetFakeManager(foo).AddRule(myRule).

I'm thinking of implementing this feature though, it would be something like this:

A.CallTo(foo).WhereMethod(x => x.Name == "MyProtectedMethod").Returns("whatever");

The syntax is not quite refined yet though.

**Edit**
The feature mentioned above is now implemented:

```
A.CallTo(foo).Where(x => x.Method.Name == "MyProtectedMethod").WithReturnType<int>().Returns(10);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the new feature. Now I can remove my own rule again.

Comment: I tried the code you provided above, but the method MyProtectedMethod is still being called.  I would expect it to return the fake return value but not to call the original method.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @stusherwin Perhaps the method isn't virtual?

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Patrik's answer, I thought it would be relevant in this post to add a tip of how you could mock a protected property member:

```
A.CallTo(foo).Where(x => x.Method.Name == "get_MyProtectedProperty").WithReturnType<int>().Returns(10);
```

This is actually how reflection treats 'getter' methods of properties.

Hope it helps :)